# Accessing local .env variables from a custom function within nestjs

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config

I have an `.env.development` file with the following variables

```
DB_NAME=db.sqlite
COOKIE_KEY=sdfjshdfjsf
```

For this I have created a `setup-app.ts` file with the `setupApp` function, where I defined a cookie `keys` value:

```
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');

export const setupApp = (app: any) => {
  app.use(
    cookieSession({
      keys: ['asdfasdf'],
    }),
  );

  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      whitelist: true,
    }),
  );
};
```

How to properly access this .env variable (`COOKIE_KEY=sdfjshdfjsf`) value within my `setupApp` function? Later I want to upload my app to Heroku and also create this `COOKIE_KEY` variable there. So it should also work later with Heroku.

I found a way in NestJS to do this via

```
keys: [this.configService.get('COOKIE_KEY')]
```

but this apparently requires a `class` with a dependency injection in the `constructor` and further complicated configurations. In my case I have only a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's just nodejs. If you want to load your env. file into `process.env` object, you can use some lib like [`dotenv`](https://npmjs.com/dotenv). `@nestjs/config` uses that lib btw

Answer (score 0):

Create new instance of ConfigService then use configService.get

```
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
// import { CookieSession } from 'cookie-session';
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

const configService = new ConfigService();

export const setupApp = (app: any) => {
  app.use(
    cookieSession({
      // keys: ['asdfasdf'],
      keys: [configService.get<string>('COOKIE_KEY')],
    }),
  );
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      whitelist: true, //doesn't allow extra property in body like admin: 
true
    }),
  );
};
```